# Why the delete operator calls the destructor and free doesn't?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, destructor, new-operator, delete-operator

I saw a game developer overload the **new** and **delete** operator on YouTube. His name is Cherno.

```
void* operator new(size_t size){
    return malloc(size);
}
void operator delete(void* pointer, size_t size){
    free(pointer);
}
```

Well, now what I did is I created a class:

```
struct MyClass{
    int my_int;
    MyClass(int a): my_int{a}{}
    ~MyClass(){cout << "MyClass is destructed" << endl;}
};
```

And I created a heap allocated object of that class in the main() function

```
int main(){
    MyClass* cls = new MyClass{10};
    // free(cls);    //Doesn't call the destructor
    delete cls;      //Does call the destructor
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
MyClass is destructed
```

So, here is my question. Why does the **delete** call the destructor and the **free()** doesn't, even if all **delete** does is that it uses the **free()** internally (I assume).

And I know that we shouldn't use **free()** on objects that are allocated using **new** operator. But even in this case the **new** operator uses **malloc()** internally

Comment: Because `delete` destroys objects and `free` only deallocates memory. `free`, like `malloc`, is a C function and knows nothing about C++.

Comment: Note that `operator new` and `operator delete` are for allocating and deallocating memory (they should really be called something like "allocate" and "deallocate", but C++ avoids adding keywords as far as possible). They do not correspond directly to the new-expression and delete-expression.

Comment: You need to distinguish between `operator delete` and `delete` _expression_. Basically, `delete` expression = destruction + `operator delete`.

Comment: `malloc` and `free` are C functions.  They know nothing about C++ objects and how they work.  `new` and `delete` OTOH, are C++ constructs and know how to deal with classes.

Comment: It simply isn't possible.  `free` doesn't know what type of pointer it's being passed, so it couldn't call a destructor even if it wanted to.

Answer (score 2):

Calling `free` on a pointer that was not created by call to `std::malloc`, `std::calloc`, `std::aligned_alloc`, or `std::realloc` is undefined behavior. Hence you cannot expect anything reasonable from your program, because you allocated memory for your `MyClass` object with `operator new`.

[docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/free)

Comment: Technically, objects are not allocated. Only their storage is allocated. Objects are then initialized (constructed) in this storage.

Comment: @ArtazaSameen, yes I read your full question, but you are wrong. "And I know that we shouldn't use free()" - it is not that "you shouldn't do this". If you do, it is UB.

Comment: you clarified one misunderstanding but the question you answer not. Why does `free` not call the desctructor? It has been iterated several times in comments, but the answer does not mention it

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number, well sorry; I thought that "free doesn't call DTor because it is [UB](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub)" is what we are looking for, and I don't see it mentioned in the comments. According to UB definition, if compiler decides to throw `std::runtime_error("free called on ptr returned by new");` in this situation, it will still be according to the standard.

Comment: free not calling destructor has nothing to do with the UB in OPs code. OPs code is just not a good example for the question they are asking. Anyhow, i think OP already got what they wanted from the duplicate (and mentioning UB is a nice addition that isnt mentioned explicitly in the dupe).

Comment: @pptaszni well if something is undefined behavoiur, then it is obvious that we shouldn't do it.